# Страница "Нет подключения к Интернету" на React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Задался задачей написать страницу "Нет подключения к Интернету" как в youtube. Но так как я новичок в реакте, не знаю с чего начать. Подскажите решением либо методом. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Это называется [**PWA**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps).

> **Прогрессивное web-приложение** — технология в web-разработке, которая визуально и функционально трансформирует сайт в приложение
> (мобильное приложение в браузере)

[**Ссылка на хабре**](https://habr.com/ru/post/418923/)

[**Википедия**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)